# Redux structure for image capturing

Tags: react-native, redux

**Hi all.**

Camera shots are taken from different places in my app. Every image will be connected to some entity in the store. For example:

1. new avatar image (conencted to user profile)
2. project cover photo (connected to project)
3. control point image/video. Several images can be connected to a "control point"

Each of (1/2/3) has its own slice in the Redux store. (3) is a bit special in that a QR-code might be read from one or more of the images and it has to match with the control point's QR code.

**One solution:**

The "add image" event of the parent screen could send it's entity type and id as props to the cameraView. This would let the SAVE_IMAGE action do it's thing directly to the store and the cameraView won't need to communicate back any information to the view that spawned the cameraView. Instead the "spawning" view  will get it's information via new props when the reducer puts the imageId in the correct place in the store.

The action might look like this:

```
function saveImageAction(imageRecord, ownerGuid, ownerType) {
  return {
    type: SAVE_IMAGE,
    payload: {
      imageRecord: imageRecord
      ownerGuId: ownerGuid,
      ownerType: ownerType
    }
  }
}
```

**Another solution:**

The modal cameraView could communicate back to the owner view and let the owner view connect to the image. I.e. the profileView/projectView/etc would take care of saving the imageId in the correct field via its own action (SAVE_PROJECT, etc).

**edit: I'm now leaning towards this solution (third)**

Before spawning a cameraView, the owning view makes up an imageGuid and sends it to the cameraView via props. Upon saving the image, the imageView dispatches a SAVE_IMAGE action which tags the image in the store with this guid.

All I need to take care of is if the user dismisses the camera view without saving an image. In this case I'll have to clear the imageGuid from the owning object (project, profile, etc).

More thoughts are very welcome. Structuring Redux is hard work for me. I'm hoping to get the hang of it soon.

Thanks,
//michael